# Error when uploading file from local file system to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, virtualbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm following Hortonworks Hadoop tutorial: https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/manage-files-on-hdfs-via-cli-ambari-files-view/section/1/#create-a-directory-in-hdfs-upload-a-file-and-list-contents.
And I was able to create a directory in HDFS, but having a problem uploading a file from my local system to the directory.

I gave root access to read and write to the user directory with the command `hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /user`. And then I gave permissions to root with the following command `hdfs dfs -chown root:hdfs /user/hadoop`.

But for some reason when I'm trying to execute the command `hdfs dfs -put sf-salaries-2011-2013.csv /user/hadoop/sf-salaries-2011-2013/sf-salaries-2011-2013.csv` - I'm getting the error:

```
put: `/user/hadoop/sf-salaries-2011-2013/sf-salaries-2011-2013.csv': No such file or directory: `hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020     /user/hadoop/sf-salaries-2011-2013/sf-salaries-2011-2013.csv'
```

Could it be the problem with port 8020? I'm following the tutorial step by step and can not figure out what I may be missing here.

Here's my terminal view:
[image]

I can see the directory created in Ambari as well (created it twice):
[image]

The first one probably has a typo (upper-case H). But as I see the directory is empty but it exists.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put in HDFS directory which is not there in HDFS. Its not with the permissions.

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hadoop/sf-salaries-2011-2013
```

The above directory is not there in HDFS, you are trying to put in the `sf-salaries-2011-2013` directory but the directory in HDFS is like `sf-salaries-2011-1013`. check out the highlights in the below picture, you can find out what you are doing wrong here.

[image]

Comment: I followed this example: https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/manage-files-on-hdfs-via-cli-ambari-files-view/section/1/#hdfs-dfs--put. But I also tried to put the file another way: `hdfs dfs -put sf-salaries-2011-2013.csv /user/hadoop/sf-salaries-2011-2013/` and it resulted in the same error: `No such file or directory` So do you think there is also a typo in the Hortonworks tutorial?

Comment: Can you put a screen shot of the hdfs dfs -ls /user/Hadoop/sf-salaries-2011-2013    ??

Comment: added the screen shot.

Comment: Try to do ls on hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/hadoop/sf-salaries-2011-2013

Comment: Any luck ? @samba